# Mariadb Json-column Insert data into empty Json_object

Tags: json, mariadb

I work with mariadb and i want to use json-column.
When i create a row, the json-column "default" value is {}. It's empty.

Exemple :
1- I create a Json_object empty.
[create json_object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owYAl.png)

2- I add a value in this json_object
[add data to json_object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqRdm.png)

But the response is null.
I want to have {"a": "b"}.

First "bad" solution would be to recreate the object :
[recreate json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWTOW.png)
I don't want to recreat a object, i want to add data.

Second "bad" solution would be to set default value non empty.
[solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l07H.png)

Comment: See [JSON_SET returns NULL instead of object](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13324).

Comment: So it's fixed to next version. I use 10.2.8 ! Thanks =)